# Jquery modal opens over my footer of my page

Tags: css, modal-dialog, footer

When I open my modal and it has great content, and its height is large, is opening on top of my footer, how do you not open up in the footer but make my content (body of the page) to automatically increase?

see below:

[image: Error]

```
    $('#lnkAdicionar').live("click", function () {
        $('#dialogClienteFornecedor').dialog({
            width: 608,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Novo Cliente e Fornecedor',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("CadastroClienteFornecedor")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    context: this,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $(this).html(result);
                    },
                });

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $('#dialogClienteFornecedor').empty();
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top',
                at: 'top',
                of: $('#divMenu')
            }
        });
    });
});
```